# Is it safe to rely on short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: c++, c++14, evaluation, short-circuiting

I like the idea how the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) works, it can save many unnecessary lines in a code. But I'm not sure how much faith can I place in that it will work with all compilers.

Let consider the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::string foo { "this is a test" };
    auto pos = foo.find_first_not_of("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ");

    if(pos != std::string::npos && ispunct(foo.at(pos)))
        std::cout << "The first non-alphabetic character is a punctuation.";
    else
        std::cout << "The string contains only alphabetic characters.";

    return (std::cout << std::endl, 0);
}
```

By the terms of short-circuit evaluation the `ispunct(foo.at(pos))` won't be evaluated and the program won't try to access an element out of bounds. Is this approach perfectly safe beyond my GCC 5.4.0 compiler?

Moreover, how about using the short-circuit evaluation outside an `if` or a `while` statement? Let say I would like to allow null pointers with appropriate safety in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename... Strings>
std::vector<std::string> pack(Strings... strs) {
    using dummy = int[];
    std::vector<std::string> out;

    (void)dummy { 0, ((void)(strs && (out.push_back({ strs }), false)), 0)... };
    return out;
}

int main() {
    const auto result = pack("foo", nullptr, nullptr, "bar", nullptr, "baz");

    for(const auto& e : result)
        std::cout << e << ' ';

    return (std::cout << std::endl, 0);
}
```

The `(strs && (out.push_back({ strs }), false))` will emplace the current `strs` into the `out` vector only if it isn't a `nullptr`. I inspected the [assembly output](https://godbolt.org/g/JKkuhr) of the code above using GCC 5.4.0 and with zero optimization level jump instructions prevent the construction of strings from null pointers. But the question remains the same: is it safe to rely on short-circuit evaluation?

Comment: The duplicate doesn't seem to cover short-circuiting a parameter pack

Comment: Of course it is safe.  That's an integral part of the definition of the && and || operator,in both C and C++. They are also guaranteed to be evaluated in order.  It is even considered good practice to rely on them.

Comment: When mixing several && and || in a test condition, make sure you use parenthesis in the appropriate place, as && has precedence over ||. which can make reading such test conditions a nightmare.  You can check the precedence of operators here http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence, but nothing beats parenthesis for readability..